# What is max number of retry attempts for Twilio sms callback?

Tags: callback, sms, twilio

Twilio has provision for configuring callback URL while sending SMS, which is notified of events relating to changes in the delivery state of SMS.

What happens if my application misses one of these callback events? Say for example when my server is down and the callback request encounters a 502 or 500 response.

Does Twilio retry the callback?

If yes, how many attempts are made before abandoning the event notification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE:  note that twilio can be configured to retry.  add `#rc=5` to the end of your webhook url and it will retry 5 times.  see https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-connection-overrides for more details

---

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio webhooks (for SMS or phone calls) do not make retry attempts to the same URL if your application fails to respond with a 200 response.

However, you can supply a fallback URL that Twilio will request with the same parameters if your primary URL fails. We recommend that this fallback URL is not part of the same application so that if your main application is down, you can recover and continue the conversation, save the errors for later or return an error message to your user.

There is more detail on how [best to use fallback URLs on the Twilio site](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security/availability-reliability).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. You might want to add this information in the API docs here https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request

Comment: Thanks I will make that suggestion!

Comment: @philnash What happens to those messages, can they be somehow later retrieved or  are they shown to the message sender as undelivered?

Comment: The messages are stored and you can retrieve them in the [message logs in the Twilio console](https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/logs) or from the [messages API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message).

Comment: @philnash Do you have any advice on how often we should retry and for how long?  It feels excessive to do it say every minute for a week, but it also seems like it would cause excessive delays if I only pulled hourly, or daily after several failures.  Where do we think the happy medium is?

Comment: @csga5000 What are you retrying? This question was about Twilio making webhooks to your application.

Comment: @philnash Typically when a user sends a text they expect that text to be delivered (even if the recipients phone is off) eventually.  It seemed it may be a good idea to retry sending the text automatically a fixed number of times for the sake of the users experience in hopes that at some point the message can be delivered

Comment: @csga5000 I think we may be talking about different things in this question. Are you asking about how many times Twilio attempts to send a message to a phone number when you use the API to send a message?

Comment: @philnash - Twilio sometimes responds before the call data has been written to database. Any ideas how I can handle that? I suppose caching active data might help, but that doesn't help us if Twilio reaches another instance of the application?

Comment: @philnash- Am I reading this correctly that I can force a retry if I respond with a 200 response? If so, which response do I need to make for Twilio to retry?

Comment: All of this is to say, I could implement failover URLs in the application, and attempt recovery, but this would take some doing. Is there a quicker fix?

Comment: @ScubaSteve I'm not sure who's database you're talking about here. What's your specific question? Perhaps it would be best to ask a new question instead?

Comment: @philnash - I'm talking about my database, not Twilio's. Problem here is that this table is very large and heavily indexed, as there's all kinds of time sensitive searches being run, so the write operations take a bit of time. 

What's happening is that twilio is making the callbacks to server before we've finished the write operation, so when we search the database for details (by Twilio SID), we're not finding anything (because it hasn't been written yet).

Comment: @philnash - What I'm hoping to do is just return a statuscode such that Twilio will retry the callback, which hopefully gives our Database time to catch up.

Comment: Returning a failure status code, like a 5xx, will cause Twilio to call your failback URL. However, this is likely not a good long term strategy. I'd probably prefer to move the recording of call data like this to a different database that does not take so long to write to so that you can respond in real time to these incoming events.

Comment: When viewing the message details in the logs (`/console/sms/logs/:MESSAGE_SID`) you can "replay" the webhook request. Is there a way to that automatically via the API, for example, when an alert is triggered? I haven't found anything, but if there is a way, I would expect to see it mentioned at https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security/availability-reliability as an alternative.

Comment: There is not. Also, notably, replaying that webhook request will not send a message if you respond with TwiML, it is more to test out that your webhook endpoint is now responding correctly.

Comment: Is it possible to have an API to query sms status by message sid?

Comment: You can [fetch a specific message by message SID and see its status using the message resource API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#fetch-a-message-resource).

Answer (score 8):

Hope this thread isn't SUPER dead...

I set out to solve this problem myself by making [twiliq.com](https://twiliq.com). Disclosure: I'm the dude that made this thing.

You set it as your backup URL endpoint and it'll replay the message as often as you configure until your server recovers.

Comment: This site has now been shutdown

Answer (score 6):

Since an answer was posted for this Twilio has added support for retry attempts on webhooks. By default it will retry once on TCP connect or TLS handshake failures, but the type of failures it retries for can be adjusted and the number of retries can be set anywhere between and including 0 and 5.

Documentation can be found here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-connection-overrides

Comment: for the lazy,  basically you configure it by adding `#rc=5` to the end of your webhook url to add 5 retry attempts.  see link above for other options aside from `rc`